# How can I mock a SQLALCHEMY query without having to mock the entire session?

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, mocking

I'm writing some unit tests for a function in my app that acts as the server for my tictactoe game. app.py hosts the server, and in it, I have a function called on_winner. on_winner basically checks if the username, received on socket emit from the client side, is the winner or loser, it queries their name in the db, updates their score, then pushes that data back to db.

I'm just writing a unit test that checks the logic of this function. In my test function, I can successfully patch everything besides the DB.session.query. I tried googling the topic but a lot of the examples I saw showed the test function with an argument other than self. I'm unsure what I should write here.

Here's the function in app.py:

```
def on_winner(data):
    """Tells everybody who'se won, and returns updated scores."""
    winner = DB.session.query(
        models.Person).filter_by(username=data['username'])
    if data['status'] == 'winner':
        winner.score += 1

    elif data['status'] == 'loser':
        winner.score -= 1

    DB.session.add(winner)
    DB.session.commit()
    ordered_scores = DB.session.query(models.Person).order_by(
        models.Person.score.desc())
    ordered_users = ordered_append(ordered_scores)
    #SOCKETIO.emit('winner', {'ordered_users': ordered_users},
     #             broadcast=True,
      #            include_self=True)
    return ordered_users
```

And this is my test file:

```
"""This file just tests that my app
correctly updates the score of winner
and loser"""
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from app import on_winner
import models

INPUT = "user"
EXPECTED_OUTPUT = "expected"
USERNAME = 'username'
STATUS = 'status'
SCORE = 'score'
LETTER = 'letter'
class WinnerTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests that the add_to_db function is working properly"""
    def setUp(self):
        self.success_test_params = [
            {
                INPUT:  {USERNAME : 'Kevin', STATUS : 'winner'},
                EXPECTED_OUTPUT: [{USERNAME : 'Joe', SCORE : 101, LETTER : 'O'}, {USERNAME : 'Kevin', SCORE : 101, LETTER : 'X'}, {USERNAME : 'Irene', SCORE : 100, LETTER : 'X'}]
            },
            {
                INPUT: {USERNAME : 'Irene', STATUS : 'loser'},
                EXPECTED_OUTPUT: [{USERNAME : 'Joe', SCORE : 101, LETTER : 'O'}, {USERNAME : 'Kevin', SCORE : 101, LETTER : 'X'}, {USERNAME : 'Irene', SCORE : 100, LETTER : 'X'}]
            },
            {
                INPUT : {USERNAME : 'Joe', STATUS : 'winner'},
                EXPECTED_OUTPUT: [{USERNAME : 'Joe', SCORE : 102, LETTER : 'O'}, {USERNAME : 'Kevin', SCORE : 101, LETTER : 'X'}, {USERNAME : 'Irene', SCORE : 100, LETTER : 'X'}]
            }
        ]
        KEVIN = models.Person(username='Kevin', score=100, letter='X')
        JOE = models.Person(username='Joe', score=101, letter='O')
        IRENE = models.Person(username='Irene', score=100, letter='X')
        self.initial_db_mock = [KEVIN, JOE, IRENE]
    def mocked_add(self, user):
        """Mocks db.session.add"""
    def mocked_commit(self):
        """Mocks db.session.commit"""
    def mocked_query(self,username):
        """Mocks query all"""
        print("You're in mocked_query")
        for person in self.initial_db_mock:
            if person[USERNAME]==username:
                return person
    def mocked_emit(self):
        """Mocks emit"""
    def ordered_mocked_query(self):
        """This function returns the list of users in descending order"""
        return sorted(self.initial_db_mock, key = lambda i : i[SCORE], reverse=True)
    def test_on_winner(self):
        """Tests the add functions. Mocks everything"""
        for test in self.success_test_params:
            with patch('app.DB.session.add', self.mocked_add):
                with patch('app.DB.session.commit', self.mocked_commit):
                    with patch('app.DB.session.query') as mocked_db_query:
                        #with patch('SOCKETIO.emit', self.mocked_emit):
                        mocked_db_query.filter_by.return_value = self.mocked_query
                        mocked_db_query.order_by.return_value = self.ordered_mocked_query
                        actual_result = on_winner(test[INPUT])
                        expected_result = test[EXPECTED_OUTPUT]
                        print (actual_result," ",expected_result)
                        self.assertEqual(len(actual_result), len(expected_result))
                        self.assertEqual(actual_result, expected_result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```